# how can i move pointer of one class to another in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I have class named `CiF` and I want to move in the constructor pointer of `CiF` to new class named `Cmanager`.
I tried something like this:

```
CiF::CiF() : Cmanager(new Cmanager(CiF THIS))
{
}
```

please help
thanks

Comment: Perhaps you can show some code (or at least some pseudocode) that demonstrates what you'd like to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code shows how a pointer of one class is given to another in ctor. I think thats what you're trying to achieve.

I HIGHLY recommend you on not using code like this, but you did not give enough information about your usecase and so I'm not able to give you alternatives.

You probably should take a look into smart pointers and general class design. (When giving pointers to any other class you need to control which class owns the object, deletes it etc)

```
class CiF;

class Cmanager
{
public:
    Cmanager() :
      cif_(0)
    {};
    void setCiF(CiF* cif)
    {
        cif_ = cif;
    }
private:
    CiF* cif_;
};

class CiF
{
public:
    CiF() :
      cmanager_(Cmanager())
    {
        cmanager_.setCiF(this);
    }

private:
    Cmanager cmanager_;
};
```

Comment: In the above case, `class CiF` should be forward declared.

Answer (score 1):

With out having a relationship between `CiF` and `Cmanager`, I think it cannot be accomplished.

```
#include <iostream>
class Cmanager
{
};

class Cif:public Cmanager
{
    Cmanager *ptr ;
    public:
    bar() : ptr(this) 
    {
    } ;
};

int main()
{
    Cif obj ;
    return 0;
}
```